# Subsonic Query Select And (OR)

Tags: subsonic2.2

i'm Using subsonic 2.0 and i need to execute the below query

**Select * from User where User ID = 1 and (Status = 2 Or Status = 3)**

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it using and `In` statement:

```
Select * from User Where UserID = 1 And Status In (2,3)

TblUserCollection vacReqColl = new Select().From(TblUser.Schema).Where(TblUser.Columns.UserI).IsEqualTo(userID).                    And(TblUser.Columns.Status).In(Status1, Status2).OrderAsc(new string[] { "CreationDate" }).ExecuteAsCollection<TblUserCollection>();
```